# Mask raster with shapefile but keep cells where polygon touches raster

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a raster which I want to mask using `terra::mask()`. In the documentation I found that you can use the argument `touches = TRUE` to include 'all cells touched by lines or polygons'. However, this does not seem to work, as it only keeps some of the cells of the raster that are touched by the polygon. Here's what I mean.

This is the raster and the overlying shapefile before masking.

[image]

This is the raster and the overlying shapefile after masking:

[image]

Clearly, not all cells are kept that touch the polygon. Here's my code:

```
shp <- sf::read_sf("Z:/AG/Ph/GIS/statistics_subcatchments/catchment_GS6_2_4326.shp") 
shp <- sf::st_transform(shp, st_crs = "EPSG:4326" |> terra::vect())


ras_crop <- terra::crop(ras_raw, shp)
ras_mask <- terra::mask(ras_crop, shp, touches = T)
```

I uploaded the raster `ras_raw`, which is the raster in the first image, and shapefile `shp` that are mentioned in the code here: https://file.io/xSBYLGBTfi55

I did try to use the `raster` package for this task instead, however, there is no option to specify that the touched cells should be kept. I also checked if this is an issue of the `crs()`, however, this is also not the case. I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution is the `extract` function from the `terra` package. A nice additional feature of it is that it also gives you the fraction of each pixel covering the polygon.